# Specifying default value for a property in relation to other property in Json.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I am wondering if there is a way to set default value for a property in relation to other property of the same class in Json.NET e.g like this:

```
public class JsonsoftExample
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]
    [DefaultValue(Start.AddHours(1))]
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish here is to populate **End** with *DateTime* value that is one hour later than **Start** in cases e.g when deserializing json to domain model and **End** value is missing or null. Like this:

```
string json = "{\"Start\": \"2017-01-01T08:00:00+01:00\"}";
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonsoftExample>(json);
```

The way I am doing it now is just inspecting later in code if **End** value is null in my domain object and if it is - populating it with desired value.

Is it feasible the way proposed in code sample or is there maybe a better simpler way except for the manual checking as in paragraph above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in the [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/), a JSON object is an ***unordered*** set of name/value pairs, so in general Json.NET does not allow one property to be set relative to another.  Json.NET is a streaming, single-pass deserializer and there's no guarantee which will appear first in the JSON.

However, when your object specifies use of a parameterized constructor via, e.g., the [`[JsonConstructor]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm#JsonConstructorAttribute) attribute, Json.NET will pre-load the JSON properties and their values then construct the object with the deserialized values.  This affords an opportunity to set the `End` property relative to the `Start` property:

```
public partial class JsonsoftExample
{
    public JsonsoftExample() { }

    [JsonConstructor]       
    JsonsoftExample(DateTime start, DateTime? end)
    {
        this.Start = start;
        this.End = end ?? Start.AddHours(1);            
    }

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }

    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

Notes:

- The names of the constructor arguments must be the same as the names of the properties, modulo case.  This is how Json.NET matches constructor arguments with JSON properties.
- Note that the `End` property is of type `DateTime` while the `end` constructor argument is of type `DateTime?`.  When `"End"` is missing from the JSON, Json.NET will pass in a `null` value into the constructor, which can be checked for to properly initialize the `End` time relative to the `Start`.
- If you don't want to serialize the `End` property when it is exactly one hour later than the start, you can use [conditional property serialization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm):

  ```
  public bool ShouldSerializeEnd()
  {
      return End != Start.AddHours(1);
  }
  ```
- The constructor does not need to be public when marked with `[JsonConstructor]`.  Properties not passed into the constructor will be populated after construction as per usual deserialization.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/A276jg).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C# 6 then probably you can do like [* Not sure if this is what you are looking to achieve]

```
[JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]    
public DateTime End { get; set; } = Start.AddHours(1);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't compile. Nor does version with "=>" instead of "="

Comment: Checked and it works only if I remove { get; set; } and use =>, but it overrides **End** value even if it is provided