# Using Newtonsoft.Json, how to insure specific deserialization order, in case deserializing one property depends on another one?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net

I am deserializing JSON to C# class using Newtonsoft.Json. Deserializing one property depends on another property's value, but when deserializing the first property, the other property is not deserialized yet, so it has the default value. I need to insure that the other property is deserialized before deserializing the first property.

I tried JsonProperty Order but it has not effect in this case

Edit: This is the C# class

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int secondVal;

    public int FirstVal { get; set; }
    public int SecondVal
    {
        get => secondVal + FirstVal;
        set => secondVal = value - FirstVal;
    }
}
```

As we see, setter and getter of SecondVal depends on FirstVal value. When deserializing a JSON that represents this class, SecondVal setter is being called, and it uses FirstVal value, which should be get from the same JSON. But at this point, FirstVal has its default value - zero in this case -, as it is not deserialized yet (this is my guess), so a wrong value is being set in SecondVal setter.

What I need is when deserializing this JSON, and SecondVal setter is being called and it uses FirstVal value, FirstVal is already being deserialized so I get its actual value instead of the default value

Comment: Can you show an example of such a json? I had no idea there was even such a thing as "dependency" on other properties, json is a container for data not for logic.

Comment: Can you share some additional details?  As specified in the [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/), a JSON object is an ***unordered** set of name/value pairs*, so in general Json.NET does not allow one property to be set relative to another, but maybe there could be some workaround we could suggest given more details, such as setting the interdependent properties in an [`OnDeserialized()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm) method, or a [parameterized constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49660649/3744182).

Comment: I would suggest posting your C# class so we can at least see the calculation you're referring to.   We could then point you in the right direction for how to work with such a thing.  Without seeing it I would suggest using a DTO class with non-calculated properties for serialization/deserialization purposes.  ( I basically was typing the same thing as @dbc above, just more slowly )

Comment: I added more explanation and code sample

Answer (score 0):

For more advanced behavior you have to use a custom JsonConverter.
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

```
public class DemoClass
{
    public string PropOrder1 { get; set; }
    public string PropOrder2 { get; set; }
}
public class DemoClassConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(MyClass));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        DemoClass demo= new DemoClass();
        demo.PropOrder1 = jo["PropOrder1"].ToObject<string>();
        
        demo.PropOrder2 = jo["PropOrder2"].ToObject<string>();

        return demo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you for some reason need to init private secondVal (I don't know what difference it makes, pls explain just because of curiosity, you can try this

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int secondVal;

    public int FirstVal { get; set; }
    public int SecondVal
    {
        get => secondVal + FirstVal;
        set => secondVal = value - FirstVal;
    }
  
    public int ThirdVal { get; set; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public MyClass(int FirstVal, int SecondVal)
    {
        this.FirstVal=FirstVal;
        this.SecondVal=SecondVal;
    }
    public MyClass() {}
}
```